# Converting a query containing MAX into an UPDATE statement in Access

Tags: sql, ms-access, sql-update

I've got a table with Years, Months, Scores and I created a query to isolate the MAX score for each month. Now I want to create an update query that will mark each item in a new column, but I'm not quite sure how given the MAX.

`SELECT a.Year, Max(a.Score) AS MaxOfScore, a.Month
FROM a
GROUP BY a.Year, a.Month, a.Score
HAVING (((a.Month) Is Not Null));`

How do I write an update statement that adds "x" to a new column, a.High?

Thanks

Comment: untagging mysql is a good start....

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that adding this as a static value to the table is what you really want to do but here's the code for that:

```
update a set a.high = b.MaxOfScore from 
a left join (
SELECT a.Year, Max(a.Score) AS MaxOfScore, a.Month
FROM a
GROUP BY a.Year, a.Month
HAVING (((a.Month) Is Not Null))
) b on a.year = b.year and a.month = b.month
```

What you'd probably want to do instead is just select the value with a query:

```
SELECT a.Year, a.Month, a.Score, b.MaxOfScore from
a left join (
SELECT a.Year, Max(a.Score) AS MaxOfScore, a.Month
FROM a
GROUP BY a.Year, a.Month
HAVING (((a.Month) Is Not Null))
) b on a.year = b.year and a.month = b.month
```

Comment: Thanks. Yes, see my comment above to Parfait about what I ended up doing. Basically, expanded off your second suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

In MS Access SQL, update queries must be updateable and hence aggregate queries cannot be joined to a unit level table. However, you can use the [Domain Aggregate functions](http://www.techonthenet.com/access/functions/domain/dmax.php). Also, if month and year are strings be sure to concatenate their values with enclosed single quotes:

```
UPDATE a
SET a.High = DMax("Score", "a", "Year=" & a.Year &  
                                " And Month=" & a.Month & 
                                " And Month Is Not Null");
```

Please note: Domain Functions are only available in SQL queries in the MS Access UI program and not in Jet/ACE SQL Engine called outside MSAccess.exe using ODBC/OLEDB.

Comment: Thanks, the "updateable" thing makes obvious sense after thinking about it and meant I had to think differently about my approach. What I did was MAKE TABLE from my SELECT query that included the primary key, updated that table with my field then ran an update statement on original table where both table primary keys were equal.

Comment: Also another approach. Glad to hear you resolved your issue. Should my answer be helpful, please accept it to confirm resolution.